# ¿Cómo subir archivos en Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo

¿Cómo puedo subir archivos a una carpeta local en Python 3 para después mostrarlos?

Tengo instalado Windows 10, uso Python 3 pyqt5 y estoy tratando de crear un sistema de ventas donde los usuarios como los clientes y proveedores puedan subir su foto a una carpeta dentro del mismo programa y obviamente mostrarla en un widget.

Esto es lo que ya vi y me da error:

**Código**

```
def abrir(self):
    ruta= 'fotos'
    archivos = ''
    fichero = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Abrir fichero")
    with open(archivos, 'rb') as fsrc:
        a = fsrc.read()
    shutil.copyfile(archivos, ruta)
```

#### **Error**

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):

>  File "C:\Users\Beto\Documents\Proyectos python\Demos\getfile.py", line 39, in abrir

>    with open(archivos, 'rb') as fsrc:

>    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

Lo cambié por esto:

```
def abrir(self):
    fichero = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Abrir fichero")
    with open(fichero) as archivo:
        a = archivo.read()
        print(a)
```

Y me da este error ahora:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Beto\Documents\Proyectos python\Demos\getfile.py", line 37, in abrir
    with open(fichero) as archivo:
TypeError: invalid file: ('C:/Users/Beto/Documents/Proyectos python/Demos/imagenes.ui', '')
```

Esta es mi nueva función:

```
def abrir(self):
    fichero, _= QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Subir archivo",
            QDir.currentPath())
    img = QImage(fichero)
    destino = 'fotos'
    if os.path.exists(fichero):
        with open(fichero, 'rb') as forigen:
            with open(destino, 'wb') as fdestino:
                copyfile(forigen, fdestino)
            print ('copiado con exito')
            # print (os.getcwd()+os.sep + 'fotos')
            self.msg.setText("Imagen subida exitosamente")
    else:
        self.msg.setText("No es una imagen")
```

Ahora tengo este nuevo error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Beto\Documents\Proyectos python\punto-de-venta -migracion\main\regclientes.py", line 212, in abrir
    with open(destino, 'wb') as fdestino:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'fotos'
```

Cambié la función por esta:

```
def abrir(self):
    fichero, _= QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Subir archivo",
            QDir.currentPath())
    # img = QImage(fichero)
    ruta = 'fotos'
    destino = os.getcwd() + os.sep +ruta + os.sep + 'ss.png'
    print(destino)
    if os.path.exists(fichero):
        with open(fichero, 'rb') as forigen:
            with open(destino, 'wb') as fdestino:
                copyfileobj(forigen, fdestino)
            print ('copiado con exito')
            self.msg.setText("Imagen subida exitosamente")
    else:
        self.msg.setText("No es una imagen")
```

Ahora si la copia pero arroja:

> failed to load image

Comment: Al agregar detalles obtienes mayor chance de obtener buenas respuestas. Edita la pregunta, coloca que tipo de Sistema operativo utilizas, qué es lo que tienes o has realizado y que esperas lograr. Saludos

Comment: ¿Subirla de dónde a dónde? ¿Es una aplicación cliente/servidor?

Comment: Es un sistema de ventas con su base de datos incrustada en el mismo programa, las imágenes serán cargadas desde la pc donde este instalado el programa hacia una carpeta que tendrá el mismo programa para luego mostrarla dentro del mismo programa @toledano

Comment: Pues sin mas detalles de tu implementación, te recomiendo que copies los archivos a su destino. Consulta la documentación: https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html - Te invito además que consultes la siguiente guía: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: No lo escribí en chino como para que no se entienda

Comment: **Es que tampoco escribiste nada en python**. Nos es imposible saber cómo ayudarte sin ser demasiado genéricos (como la solución que te pone en el comentario @toledano)

Comment: y q se supone q tengo q escribir de python para q le puedan entender

Comment: Te entendemos perfectamente. La respuesta es "mírate el módulo [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/shutil.html)". Si quieres más detalles, necesitamos más detalles. Si has probado algún código y no te funciona, adjunta un resumen con la parte problemática. El único modo de concretar más la respuesta es viendo qué código has hecho.

Comment: Consulta la documentación de la función para resolver tu nuevo error: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html#details

Comment: ¿`destino = 'fotos'` es un directorio? Si es un directorio, entonces debes agregarlo al nombre de tu archivo para construir la ruta completa, por ejemplo en `c:\fotos\mifoto.jpg`. Por lo tanto debes _concatenar_ la ruta al nombre del archivo para formar la ruta completa.

Comment: Disculpa no entiendo tu ejemplo @toledano soy muy novato en esto

Answer (score 1):

El error que tienes es que la variable `archivos` siempre permanece vacía. No sé cuál sea tu intención al usarla, tal vez esperas recibir una lista de archivos del cuadro de diálogo o algo así.

El caso es que el o los archivos que selecciona el usuario en el cuadro de diálogo que hace `QFileDialog` se quedan en la variable `fichero` **¡que nunca usas!**.

El caso es que pides abrir el archivo que se encuentra en la variable `archivos` que al estar vacía provoca de manera correctísima el error que ves.

Ya que el archivo que selecciona el usuario está en `fichero` tal vez sea ese el que debas abrir.

```
def abrir(self):
    ruta= 'fotos'
    archivos = ''     # ### nunca se usa
    fichero = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Abrir fichero")
    with open(fichero, 'rb') as fsrc:
        a = fsrc.read()
    shutil.copyfile(fichero, ruta)
```

> **Nota**
>   No queda claro en el fragmento que compartes para qué lees el archivo abierto, pero bueno. El origen del error está resuelto y también una posible solución.